# Safe way to update database in ormlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

My app used `ormlite` to communicate with Sqlite database. There are many screens that get data from `ormlite`. The problem is I want to update the database in background without user' knowledge (it's transparent to user) and my app use some `CursorAdapters` and `Loaders` to get data. 
The behavior look like this: my app check if there is new version in server, it will download new db file from server, then change current db file from local by new server db file in ormlite helper. While update progress is happening, user can change screen or view data from db normally (I just use the **select** query) 

I have searched some answer, they advised use `onUpgrade` method, but how can I apply this in my case, because I want to change completely the database file? And how can I switch the database while selecting data? 
Here is my db helper:

```
  public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, "document.sqlite", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Category.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Book.class);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Ln.e(ex);
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion,
        int newVersion) {
    try{
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Category.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Book.class, true);

        // get new one
        onCreate(db, connectionSource);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Ln.e(ex);
    }       
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation in my project in which I had to refresh database with new data after checking for new data.After trying so many methods Finally I reached at one solution.I do not know if that solution is optimal one but after testing it is working fine.

Solution is as follows:-

I am getting new data in json form so I am creating a new blank database with temp_original-database-name.db and then populating it with new data(in your case you have complete database downloading from server , so you do not need extra helper for creating temporary database). After this data is populated then I am renaming this database temp_original-database-name.db to original-database-name.db using file system methods.

I have done testing and original helper instance used for original database still exists even after still second rename of database operation.and everything works fine.

Hope this can help.Please tell me if this helps and if you have any other question regarding this.

Comment: Actually, I replaced my exist db file with the new one by using copy and replace file method (you can't use rename because one folder can't accept 2 files has the same name). And this way can work. I just tested and saw the copy task took only 100 - 300 ms. But my data can be growth up and larger, so the copy task may take more time. So I'm afraid error can occurred while replace db file.